# why no implicit conversion of nil into Hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, pg-search

after setup a search into a serializer!
Rails spits out

> no implicit conversion of nil into Hash

So, please someone can point out whats wrong with this code?

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def results
    results_query = PgSearch.multisearch(params[:q]).paginate(page: page, per_page: 20)
    result = results_query.map(&:searchable).map do |result_item|
      case result_item.class.name
      when 'Post'
        PostSerializer.new(result_item)
 
      else
        raise NotImplementedError
      end
    end

    render json: {
      items: result,
      page: page,
      pages: results_query.total_pages
    }
  end

  def page
    params[:page] || 1
  end

  def serialize(data, serializer)
    ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(data, each_serializer: serializer)
  end
end
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What line of code is the error coming from?

Comment: seems this one:    results_query = PgSearch.multisearch(params[:q]).includes([:searchable]).paginate(page: page, per_page: 20)

Comment: Please provide log output (especially the line that shows the parameters that were parsed from the HTTP request) and an actual stack trace so it's possible to help you somewhat efficiently. Otherwise it's really hard to help.

Comment: @ClemensKofler , ive added the screenshot of stacktrace. is ok?

Comment: I had a similar problem which was solved after upgrading the pg_search gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your case statement isn't checking many values, you could always make it into a standard if/else statement:

```
if result_item && result.class.name == 'Post'
    PostSerializer.new(result_item)
else
    raise NotImplementedError
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, on the screenshots you've provided we can see the log message specifies that the error is on line 5.

According to your code, line 5 is: `case result_item.class.name`

The error message is `TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into Hash)`.

You're trying to get the `class` then the `name` of `result_item`. So the problem is with `result_item` which is equal to `nil`.

In order the resolve your problem you might want to check the ouput of `results_query.map(&:searchable).map`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot you've provided, I've quickly checked the source code. The offending line seems to be this one: https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search/blob/master/lib/pg_search/document.rb#L22. The only reason why this would raise the described `TypeError` is if  `PgSearch.multisearch_options` is `nil` – which, as far as I understand the code, would only be possible if you accidentally overwrote it in a wrong way. So I'd suggest doublechecking your global setup for `PgSearch.multisearch_options` to make sure this is actually set.

The east way to check the setting is by using a debugger or putting something like `puts PgSearch.multisearch_options` or `Rails.logger.info 'PgSearch.multisearch_options'` into the controller directly above the call that's failing.